# Do the algebraic properties of the exponential and log functions specify them uniquely in probability theory?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-mechanics

I come from a physics background and in classical mechanics, we construct a Hamiltonian function whose partial derivatives generates a vector field, two independent systems are assigned a total Hamiltonian which is the algebraic sum of the Hamiltonians for the isolated systems.

In statistical mechanics, Liouville's theorem requires that in equilibrium, the probability that a system's dynamical variables have specific values is a function of the value Hamiltonian for those specific values. So the standard probability theory argument that the probability to measure state a in system A and state b in system B for independent systems A and B is the product of the individual probabilities: $Pr(a \text{ & } b) = Pr(a)*Pr(b)$. This is essentially a quick derivation of the maxwell-boltzmann distribution.

I've seen this argument about probability theory in several places, and can easily see that the exponential satisfies the requirement.

So I think my question is essentially this, does
$$
f(a+b) = f(a)*f(b) \\
f(x) > 0 \text{ for all real x} \\
$$

uniquely specify that $f(x)=Ae^{cx}$? Or is there some other consideration that I must be overlooking?

Comment: Yes, *if* $f$ is required to be continuous. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation

Comment: You need a regularity assumption on $f$. Demanding that $f$ is measurable suffices, demanding it be continuous makes the proof easy (and, by the way, $A = 1$ is necessary).

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you. I tried proving this with Diff Eq's like the answer below, but I didn't think to use $f(a+0) = f(a)*f(0)$ like they did on that page there. I'm actually really happy you linked that though. I never even realized there was a stronger justification for the form of a linear function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is a differentiable function, taking a derivative with respect to $b$ means that
$$f'(a+b)=f(a)f'(b).$$
Now substitute $b=0$  to get the differential equation $f'(a)=f(a) f'(0)$ which has the solution $f(x) = A e^{f'(0) x}$. Thus $f'(x) = f'(0) A e^{f'(0) x}$. Solving for $f'(0)$ gives $f'(0)=Af'(0)$ which is only true if $A=1$ or $f'(0)=0$. In the latter case we end up with the constant function $f=1$ (since $A=A^2$). Otherwise, the solution is $f(x) = A e^{c x}$ where choosing $c$ chooses $f'(0)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried a similar approach, but my argument wasn't as streamlined as this and it made me unsure. Thanks again.